# Error: NG0204 with no specific details after Angular upgrade from 8 to 14

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8, angular14

I have been working on this task to upgrade from angular 8 to 14. After upgrading to 14 I am seeing this Error: NG0204 error in the console on serving my app. No additional information is provided (see image attached)

[image]

Seems like the error happens in index.html when we reach the `<app-root>` selector. Hence, the app component constructor doesn't load either.

Any idea what this could be related to?

I have tried debugging but couldn't understand whats going on here since theres no additional details in the error.

Comment: You're running your app in prod mode. Run it in devmode for better logging informations & errors

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler, I have added a configuration in my angular.json to replace the env file with the local env file and run it likewise `ng serve --configuration=local` but still see the same. Tried development instead of local too but same results

Comment: The reason why your application is running in prod mode could be that this is the default since v12. For more details and a fix for that issue, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77066046/5470544).