# Compile time very slow after upgrading from angular 8 to 15

Tags: angular, angular-cli

after upgrade whenever i run ng serve or make some changes in the file ,the compile time is 1 minute before it was 5seconds.i used to see something while compiling as it takes something from webpack now everytime i save changes it shows generation browsing application bundles(phase:sealing)

this is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "hh",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve -o --configuration=en",
    "startSSL": "ng serve --ssl true --ssl-cert ./ssl/server.crt --ssl-key ./ssl/server.key",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e",
    "build-dev": "node --max_old_space_size=8048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng build --prod --aot --outputHashing=all",
    "build-serve": "node --max_old_space_size=8048 ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng serve",
    "build-locale:eng": "ng build --prod --i18n-locale en --i18n-format xlf --i18n-file src/locale/messages.en.xlf --output-path=dist",
    "build-locale:en": "ng build --prod --i18n-locale en --i18n-format xlf --i18n-file src/locale/messages.en.xlf --output-path=dist/en --baseHref /en/",
    "build-locale:ar": "ng build --prod --i18n-locale ar --i18n-format xlf --i18n-file src/locale/messages.ar.xlf --output-path=dist/ar --baseHref /ar/",
    "build-locale": "npm run build-locale:eng && npm run build-locale:ar && npm run build-locale:en",
    "build:browser:prod": "ng build --prod",
    "build:browser:serverless": "npm run build-locale:eng && npm run build-locale:ar && npm run build-locale:en",
    "build:serverless": "npm run build:browser:serverless && npm run build:server:serverless",
    "build:prod": "npm run build:browser:prod && npm run build:server:prod",
    "server": "node local.js",
    "build:prod:deploy": "npm run build:prod && npm run deploy",
    "build:serverless:deploy": "npm run build:serverless && npm run deploy",
    "deploy": "serverless deploy",
    "build:server:prod": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors",
    "build:server:serverless": "webpack --config webpack.server.config.js --progress --colors"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/core": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular-devkit/schematics": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular-slider/ngx-slider": "^2.0.4",
    "@angular/animations": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/cdk": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/common": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/core": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/forms": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/localize": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/material": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/material-moment-adapter": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/router": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^15.2.9",
    "@auth0/angular-jwt": "^2.1.1",
    "@ctrl/ngx-emoji-mart": "^8.2.0",
    "@kolkov/ngx-gallery": "^2.0.1",
    "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^7.0.0",
    "@ng-toolkit/serverless": "^8.0.3",
    "@ng-toolkit/universal": "^7.1.2",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "@schematics/angular": "^15.2.9",
    "@solidexpert/ng-click-outside": "^15.0.2",
    "@sweetalert2/ngx-sweetalert2": "^5.0.1",
    "@tinymce/tinymce-angular": "3.5.1",
    "@types/jquery": "^3.3.34",
    "angular-calendar": "^0.31.0",
    "angular-highcharts": "^15.0.1",
    "angular2-uuid": "^1.1.1",
    "angularx-social-login": "2.2.0",
    "aws-sdk": "^2.713.0",
    "aws-serverless-express": "^3.2.0",
    "bootstrap": "^4.3.1",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^3.32.0",
    "cors": "~2.8.4",
    "cp-cli": "^1.1.0",
    "date-fns": "^2.29.3",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "hammerjs": "^2.0.8",
    "highcharts": "^7.1.2",
    "i18n": "^0.15.1",
    "jquery": "^3.4.1",
    "moment": "^2.29.4",
    "ng-recaptcha": "^11.0.0",
    "ngx-autosize": "^2.0.4",
    "ngx-bootstrap": "^10.2.0",
    "ngx-clipboard": "^14.0.2",
    "ngx-color-picker": "^14.0.0",
    "ngx-device-detector": "^1.3.5",
    "ngx-image-cropper": "^6.3.4",
    "ngx-malihu-scrollbar": "7.0.0",
    "ngx-mat-select-search": "^3.3.3",
    "ngx-pagination": "^6.0.3",
    "ngx-select-dropdown": "^1.0.1",
    "ngx-swiper-wrapper": "^8.0.2",
    "ngx-translate-multi-http-loader": "^3.0.0",
    "npm": "^6.9.0",
    "rxjs": "^7.8.1",
    "sass-loader": "^13.2.0",
    "sweetalert2": "^8.19.0",
    "tinymce": "^5.10.7",
    "tslib": "^2.2.0",
    "videogular2": "^6.4.0",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/cli": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^15.2.9",
    "@angular/language-service": "^15.2.9",
    "@types/core-js": "^2.5.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.0.0",
    "codelyzer": "^5.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.99.1",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~6.4.2",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.0.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.2",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "opencollective": "^1.0.3",
    "protractor": "~7.0.0",
    "serverless": "1.40.0",
    "serverless-apigw-binary": "^0.4.4",
    "ts-loader": "4.2.0",
    "ts-node": "~7.0.0",
    "tslint": "~5.11.0",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "webpack-cli": "2.1.2"
  }
}
```

this is my angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "cli": {
    "analytics": false
  },
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "hh": {
      "i18n": {
        "locales": {
          "ar": {
            "translation": "src/locale/hh_Arabic.xlf",
            "baseHref": ""
          },
          "en": {
            "translation": "src/locale/messages.en.xlf",
            "baseHref": ""
          }
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "app",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        }
      },
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "aot": true,
            "outputPath": "dist/hh",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/touch-icon-iphone.png",
              "src/touch-icon-ipad.png",
              "src/touch-icon-iphone-retina.png",
              "src/touch-icon-ipad-retina.png",
              "src/assets",
              {
                "glob": "**/*",
                "input": "node_modules/tinymce",
                "output": "/tinymce/"
              },
              "src/manifest.webmanifest"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss",
              "node_modules/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.css"
            ],
            "scripts": [
              "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
              "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js",
              "node_modules/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js",
              "node_modules/tinymce/tinymce.min.js",
              "node_modules/tinymce/themes/silver/theme.js",
              "node_modules/tinymce/plugins/advlist/plugin.min.js",
              "node_modules/tinymce/plugins/anchor/plugin.min.js",
              "node_modules/tinymce/plugins/autolink/plugin.min.js",
              "node_modules/tinymce/plugins/autoresize/plugin.min.js",
              "node_modules/tinymce/plugins/autosave/plugin.min.js",
              "node_modules/tinymce/plugins/bbcode/plugin.min.js",
              "node_modules/tinymce/plugins/charmap/plugin.min.js",
              "node_modules/tinymce/plugins/code/plugin.min.js",
              "node_modules/tinymce/plugins/codesample/plugin.min.js",
              "node_modules/tinymce/plugins/colorpicker/plugin.min.js",
              "node_modules/tinymce/plugins/contextmenu/plugin.min.js",
              "node_modules/tinymce/plugins/directionality/plugin.min.js",
              "node_modules/tinymce/plugins/emoticons/plugin.min.js",
              "node_modules/tinymce/plugins/fullpage/plugin.min.js",
              "node_modules/tinymce/plugins/fullscreen/plugin.min.js",
              "node_modules/tinymce/plugins/help/plugin.min.js",
              "node_modules/tinymce/plugins/hr/plugin.min.js",
              "node_modules/tinymce/plugins/image/plugin.min.js",
              "node_modules/tinymce/plugins/imagetools/plugin.min.js",
              "node_modules/tinymce/plugins/importcss/plugin.min.js",
              "node_modules/tinymce/plugins/insertdatetime/plugin.min.js",
              "node_modules/tinymce/plugins/legacyoutput/plugin.min.js",
              "node_modules/tinymce/plugins/link/plugin.min.js",
              "node_modules/tinymce/plugins/lists/plugin.min.js",
              "node_modules/tinymce/plugins/media/plugin.min.js",
              "node_modules/tinymce/plugins/nonbreaking/plugin.min.js",
              "node_modules/tinymce/plugins/noneditable/plugin.min.js",
              "node_modules/tinymce/plugins/pagebreak/plugin.min.js",
              "node_modules/tinymce/plugins/paste/plugin.min.js",
              "node_modules/tinymce/plugins/preview/plugin.min.js",
              "node_modules/tinymce/plugins/print/plugin.min.js",
              "node_modules/tinymce/plugins/quickbars/plugin.min.js",
              "node_modules/tinymce/plugins/save/plugin.min.js",
              "node_modules/tinymce/plugins/searchreplace/plugin.min.js",
              "node_modules/tinymce/plugins/spellchecker/plugin.min.js",
              "node_modules/tinymce/plugins/tabfocus/plugin.min.js",
              "node_modules/tinymce/plugins/table/plugin.min.js",
              "node_modules/tinymce/plugins/template/plugin.min.js",
              "node_modules/tinymce/plugins/textcolor/plugin.min.js",
              "node_modules/tinymce/plugins/textpattern/plugin.min.js",
              "node_modules/tinymce/plugins/toc/plugin.min.js",
              "node_modules/tinymce/plugins/visualblocks/plugin.min.js",
              "node_modules/tinymce/plugins/visualchars/plugin.min.js",
              "node_modules/tinymce/plugins/wordcount/plugin.min.js"
            ],
            "allowedCommonJsDependencies": [
              "url",
              "angular-calendar",
              "date-fns",
              "aws-sdk",
              "tinymce",
              "highcharts",
              "moment",
              "sweetalert2",
              "angular2-uuid",
              "swiper"
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "10mb",
                  "maximumError": "15mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb"
                }
              ],
              "serviceWorker": false,
              "ngswConfigPath": "ngsw-config.json"
            },
            "ar": {
              "aot": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb"
                }
              ],
              "i18nMissingTranslation": "ignore",
              "localize": [
                "ar"
              ]
            },
            "en": {
              "aot": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "6kb"
                }
              ],
              "i18nMissingTranslation": "error",
              "localize": [
                "en"
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "hh:build",
            "port": 4200
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "hhhh:build:production"
            },
            "ar": {
              "browserTarget": "hhhh:build:ar"
            },
            "en": {
              "browserTarget": "hhhh:build:en"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "hhhh:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "src/karma.conf.js",
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets",
              "src/manifest.webmanifest"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "hhhh-e2e": {
      "root": "e2e/",
      "projectType": "application",
      "prefix": "",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "hhhh:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "devServerTarget": "hhhh:serve:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
            "exclude": [
              "**/node_modules/**"
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "hhhh"
}
```

and this is my tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compileOnSave": false,
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./",
    "outDir": "./dist/out-tsc",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "declaration": false,
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "importHelpers": true,
    "target": "ES2022",
    "typeRoots": [
      "node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "lib": [
      "ES2022",
      "dom"
    ],
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "useDefineForClassFields": false
  },
}
```

how do i fix the slow compile on every changes that i make,now for every change i make,i have to wait for 1 minute for it to compile

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TL;DR your `ng serve` is slow because your code is being minified / uglified / ...

Your `angular.json` looks strange to me, you do not have a `development` configuration set up. Since Angular 12, when not specifying any options, a production build will be performed, including minification / uglification / ..., see the [Angular v12 blog post](https://blog.angular.io/angular-v12-is-now-available-32ed51fbfd49). This takes time. It should not be done for your development server. To prevent it, you need an additional `"development"` configuration. Change your `angular.json` like the following:

```
{
  // ...
  "architect": {
    "build": {
      "configurations": {
        "development": {
          "buildOptimizer": false,
          "optimization": false,
          "vendorChunk": true,
          "extractLicenses": false,
          "sourceMap": true,
          "namedChunks": true,
          // your scripts / styles / ...
        }
      }
    },
    "serve": {
      "configurations": {
        // ... your other configurations
        "development": {
          "browserTarget": "hhhh:build:development"
        }
      },
      "defaultConfiguration": "development"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: JSON Derulo rules!