Can't access lexical declaration 'rm' before initialization
im working on a Angular 13 project using webpack and recently I started getting this error after making base classes and adding more inheritance:

Can't access lexical declaration 'rm' before initialization


I know this is some kinda hoisting problem and Im already organising my project to have export files where I export each folder seperately.
I got that error before and fixed it by using the export files, but this is kinda different. I dont know where "rm" is coming from and the sourcemap stopped working too. This is in dev mode on a local server (ng serve). I have no clue which files could cause that error.
My export files look like that
/** Base interfaces */
export * from './base/i-plan.interface'
export { IInteractive } from './i-interactive-object.interface'
export { IInteractivePlan } from './i-interactive-planer-object.interface'
export { IElementBase } from './i-element-base.interface'

/** Base classes */
export * from './base/column-base'
export * from './base/cube-base'
export * from './base/element-base'

/** 3D Components */
export * from './base/column-3d-base'
export * from './base/cube-3d-base'
export * from './base/element-3d-base'
export * from './base/system-base'
export * from './base/plan-base'

/** Specific implementations */
export * from './piece'
export * from './transfer-object-base'
export * from './selection-history'

Importing like that
import { Planer, Piece } from 'ts-planer';

This is the line which the error is point
import * as THREE from 'three'
import { RoomObject3D } from './view/room-object-3d'

... imports
export class RoomObject3D extends Object3DBase implements IInteractiveRoomObject {

Any help appreaciated!
Let me know if I can give more information
Thanks
Update: I got the sourcemap to work again. I know which file is not initialized now. I dont really know what to do next. The project is pretty big and I implemented these base classes, which affected quite a wide range of files in the project. How can I track back or how do I find out how to order the imports and exports?

Please add a minimal reproducible code example of the issue. It seems like you are using a variable before it's initialized. See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Cant_access_lexical_declaration_before_init Also try to reproduce the error in dev mode and with source mapping, and you will see which part of your code causes the issue.

Your config seems wrong, it looks like in your dev server, source mapping is disabled and optimization is enabled. This makes it much harder for you to debug your app and spot the issue. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77066228/5470544

Thanks, I was able to get the sourcemap to work again. It now points on one class that extends another one, pointing towards the definition. But where do I go from here? I already tried moving the export to different locations in the file and also tried different import techniques as well as moving imports up and down.

Please edit your question and add a minimal reproducible code example of the issue.

How would I reproduce a error I dont understand?

Break down the error. Temporarily remove things that you think are unrelated to the error. In the end you will have a minimal reproducible example.

I solved it by removing exports that didnt follow the folder structure. They were accidentally created when moving files.
For example I was having in the root index file exports of UI elements that have their own index file.
